# Java enum garbage collection & enum variable differences

Tags: java, enums, garbage-collection

I have a question regarding the java garbage collection and enum types.
Lets say I have an enum like so:

```
enum ConnectionHelper {
INSTANCE;

private boolean initialized = false;
private static int someVar;


ConnectionHelper initialize() {
    if (!initialized) {
        // Do some initialisation...
        someVar = 10;

        // NOTE: 1
        initialized = true;
    }
    return this;
}
void start() {
    // NOTE: 2
    if (!initialized) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("ConnectionHelper has to be initialized.");
    }

    // do some work...
}
```

1. Now is there a scenario where initialized may revert back to FALSE due to the garbage collector? The reason I'm asking because if thats the case I need to take additional precautions for this scenario.
2. And also, if I represent en singleton with an enum, would it matter if I use static or non-static variables for state? For example, in this example, there are two variables; someVar and initialised, would it make a difference to question 1 if initialized was static as well? Or if both were non-static?

   Thanks!

Comment: `INSTANCE` can't be garbage collected because `ConnectionHelper` has a reference to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can answer all kind of “will the garbage collector make this program behave strangely” questions with “no”, in general. The very purpose of a garbage collector is to clean up the memory of *unused* objects transparently, without your program even noticing. Producing an observable behavior like a variable flipping from `true`to `false` is definitely outside the actions allowed for a garbage collector.

That said, your program is not thread safe. If multiple threads access your `ConnectionHelper` without additional synchronization, they may perceive inconsistent results, including seeing `false` for the `initialized` variable while another thread already saw `true` for it at an earlier time from an external clock’s perspective, or seeing `true` for `initialized` while still not seeing the value of `10` written for `someVar`.

The solution is simple. Don’t implement a superfluous lazy initialization. The `enum` constants are initialized during the class initialization, which is already lazy (as specified in [JLS §12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)) and made thread safe (as specified in [JLS §12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)) by the JVM.

```
enum ConnectionHelper {
    INSTANCE;
    private static final int someVar = 10;
    void start() {
    // do some work, use the already initialized someVar...
    }
}
```

or

```
enum ConnectionHelper {
    INSTANCE;
    private final int someVar = 10;
    void start() {
    // do some work, use the already initialized someVar...
    }
}
```

or

```
enum ConnectionHelper {
    INSTANCE;
    private final int someVar;
    ConnectionHelper() {
        someVar = 10; // as place-holder for more complex initialization
    }
    void start() {
    // do some work, use the already initialized someVar...
    }
}
```

it doesn’t matter whether you declare the variable `static` or not.

The first thread calling `start()` will perform the class initialization, including the initialization of `someVar`. If other threads call the method while the initialization is still ongoing, they will wait for its completion. After the completion of the initialization, all threads may execute the `start()` method using the initialized values without any slowdown.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate answer. Though, if for example you have a class with a static variable (non-final) which is modified in a field. I've seen android examples where memory usage has been forced up to an out of memory situation where the static variable has in fact been garbage collected and became null. Do you have an explanation for this behaviour or is it due to the android JVM implementation? Thanks!

Comment: Well, Android is not Java. You’re converting software written in Java to Android software. Besides that, it’s a typical pattern for mobile software to restart software on demand, so everything without persistence gets reset to its initial state. Which is the reason why such apps make every relevant thing persistent.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collection is not expected on enum types. Your `ConnectionHelper.INSTANCE` can not be dereferenced, so the object will always be kept in memory once instantiated.

So, to your questions:

AD 1: No, it can not revert. The only way to set it back to `false` is to set it manually.

AD 2: No difference for a singleton. There would be a difference if you had more instances, as they would share `static` variables and not the usual ones.

Comment: If you call ConnectionHelper.INSTANCE.start() it will be thrown.

Comment: My bad. For some reason I thought `initialize()` is the constructor, not a simple method.